# None of the NMinimize methods leads to the answers of the equation

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The following 10 equations has one set of exact answer using NSolve in Mathematica 9.0.0.0 (for positive c2, alpha1, alpha3, beta1, beta3, A1 and A3):

```
eq1[mpionp_] := -2 c2 + 2 d2 + 4 c4a alpha1^2 + 4 e3a beta3 == 
   0.018769 + mpionp^2;
eq2[mpionp_] := -4 c2 d2 + 8 c4a d2 alpha1^2 - 16 e3a^2 alpha3^2 + 
    8 e3a d2 beta3 == 0.018769 mpionp^2;
 eq3 = -2 c2 + 2 d2 + 12 c4a alpha1^2 - 4 e3a beta3 == 3.133076`;
eq4 = -4 c2 d2 + 24 c4a d2 alpha1^2 - 16 e3a^2 alpha3^2 - 
    8 e3a d2 beta3 == 2.0866380304`;
eq5 = -2 A1 - 2 c2 alpha1 + 4 c4a alpha1^3 + 4 e3a alpha3 beta1 + 
    4 e3a alpha1 beta3 == 0;
eq6 = -2 A3 - 2 c2 alpha3 + 4 c4a alpha3^3 + 8 e3a alpha1 beta1 == 0;
eq7 = 4 e3a alpha1 alpha3 + 2 d2 beta1 == 0;
eq8 = 4 e3a alpha1^2 + 2 d2 beta3 == 0;
eq9 = (0.09263098833543772` alpha1)/(
   beta1 Sqrt[
     1 - (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3)))/Sqrt[
      64 e3a^2 alpha3^2 + 
       4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3))^2]] + 
    alpha1 Sqrt[
     1 + (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3)))/Sqrt[
      64 e3a^2 alpha3^2 + 
       4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3))^2]]) == alpha1;
eq10[t_] := A3/A1 == t;

   Eqs[mpionp_, t_] := 
  eq1[mpionp] && eq2[mpionp] && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && eq6 && eq7 && 
   eq8 && eq9 && eq10[t] && alpha1 >= 0 && c2 \[Element] Reals && 
   beta1 > 0;
parameters = {c2, d2, e3a, c4a, alpha1, alpha3, beta1, beta3, A1, A3};

solexact=NSolve[Eqs[1.2, 20], parameters]
```

> {{c2 -> 0.158201, d2 -> 0.615064, e3a -> -1.74843, c4a -> 47.036,
>   alpha1 -> 0.0606073, alpha3 -> 0.0720951, beta1 -> 0.0248421,    beta3
>   -> 0.0208837, A1 -> 0.000665807, A3 -> 0.0133161}}

First: The NSolve doesn't have any answers in Mathematica 10.0.1.0.

EDIT 1: As Daniel said, it is possible to get the same answers as in Mathematica 9, by adding Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix" to the NSolve code, i.e.,

```
solexact=NSolve[Eqs[1.2, 20], parameters, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]
```

Second: If instead of NSolve, I use NMinimize function to find the parameters:

```
eq1a[mpionp_] := -2 c2 + 2 d2 + 4 c4a alpha1^2 + 
   4 e3a beta3 - (0.018769 + mpionp^2);
eq2a[mpionp_] := -4 c2 d2 + 8 c4a d2 alpha1^2 - 16 e3a^2 alpha3^2 + 
   8 e3a d2 beta3 - (0.018769 mpionp^2);
 eq3a = -2 c2 + 2 d2 + 12 c4a alpha1^2 - 4 e3a beta3 - 3.133076`;
eq4a = -4 c2 d2 + 24 c4a d2 alpha1^2 - 16 e3a^2 alpha3^2 - 
   8 e3a d2 beta3 - 2.0866380304`;
eq5a = -2 A1 - 2 c2 alpha1 + 4 c4a alpha1^3 + 4 e3a alpha3 beta1 + 
   4 e3a alpha1 beta3;
eq6a = -2 A3 - 2 c2 alpha3 + 4 c4a alpha3^3 + 8 e3a alpha1 beta1;
eq7a = 4 e3a alpha1 alpha3 + 2 d2 beta1;
eq8a = 4 e3a alpha1^2 + 2 d2 beta3;
eq9a = (0.09263098833543772` alpha1)/(
   beta1 Sqrt[
     1 - (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3)))/Sqrt[
      64 e3a^2 alpha3^2 + 
       4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3))^2]] + 
    alpha1 Sqrt[
     1 + (2 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3)))/Sqrt[
      64 e3a^2 alpha3^2 + 
       4 (c2 + d2 - 2 (c4a alpha1^2 + e3a beta3))^2]]) - alpha1;
eq10a[t_] := A3/A1 - t;

Eqsa[mpionp_, t_] := 
 eq1a[mpionp]^2 + eq2a[mpionp]^2 + eq3a^2 + eq4a^2 + eq5a^2 + eq6a^2 +
   eq7a^2 + eq8a^2 + eq9a^2 + eq10a[t]^2
imax = 10;

Table[
 NMinimize[{Eqsa[1.2, 20], alpha1 >= 0 && c2 \[Element] Reals}, 
  parameters, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "RandomSeed" -> i}], {i, 
  imax}]
```

Then none of the sets are close to the exact solutions of NSolve. I've tried "DifferentialEvolution", "NelderMead" and "SimulatedAnnealing" methods and none of them is good to minimize this function.

I know that A1, A3, alpha1, alpha3, beta1 and beta3 are positive. If I use these conditions in NMinimize

```
Table[
 NMinimize[{Eqsa[1.2, 20], 
   alpha1 >= 0 && c2 \[Element] Reals && beta1 > 0 && A1 > 0 && 
    A3 > 0 && alpha3 > 0}, parameters, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "RandomSeed" -> i}], {i, imax}]
```

Still the answers are too far from the exact answers. My question is that how  can I get better answers from NMinimize? (Here NSolve works, but I have some equations which do not have answers using NSolve and so I should use NMinimize. Therefore this is a test for future works.)

Thanks.

Comment: Try Rationalizing all the real values in your input and then use WorkingPrecision-> 20 say. See what happens. For example: Rationalize[0.018769,0]

Comment: Something fishy seems to be going on here when I substituted the NSolve solution that you have posted into the equations, I get {False,False}. In[14]:= Eqs[1.2, 
  20] /. {{c2 -> 0.158201, d2 -> 0.615064, e3a -> -1.74843, 
   c4a -> 47.036, alpha1 -> 0.0606073, alpha3 -> 0.0720951, 
   beta1 -> 0.0248421, beta3 -> 0.0208837, A1 -> 0.000665807, 
   A3 -> 0.0133161}, {c2 -> 0.158201, d2 -> 0.615064, e3a -> 1.23878, 
   c4a -> 23.6114, alpha1 -> 0.0855419, alpha3 -> 0.101756, 
   beta1 -> -0.0350625, beta3 -> -0.0294756, A1 -> 0.000939729, 
   A3 -> 0.0187946}}

Out[14]= {False, False}

Comment: @ Lotus For all the equations except eq5, eq6 and eq7, Eqs[1.2, 20][[1]] /. sol[[1]] is True. For eq5, eq6 and eq7, Eqs[1.2, 20][[7]] /. sol[[1]] is False but For example: Eqs[1.2, 20][[7, 1]] /. sol[[1]] is of the order 10^-18 which is not exactly zero but very close to it.

Comment: @Lotus One should not try to verify equality by substituting an approximate value into an equation. What can work well, with some modifications I won't go into, is to substitute into an expression and assess whether the residual (that is, the evaluation) is "sufficiently" small.

Comment: In version 10 there is now a documented way to get the behavior of prior versions for `NSolve`. Set `Method->"EndomorphismMatrix"`. This does not address your question but might at least get you to where there is no degradation in behavior.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks a lot. Yes, by adding Method->"EndomorphismMatrix" to the NSolve, I get the answers similar to the answers in Mathematica 9. But unfortunately,  NMinimize can't approach to these sets of answers. May be I have missed some thing important.

Comment: I seriously doubt these can be solved via minimization or numerical rootfinding for that matter, unless there is a very good idea of starting points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding all the constraints to the NMinimize code will give one set of parameters which is very close to the exact solution from NSolve.

```
Table[NMinimize[{Eqsa[1.2, 20], 
   alpha1 > 0 && alpha3 > 0 && beta1 > 0 && beta3 > 0 && A1 > 0 && 
    c2 \[Element] Reals && c2 > 0}, parameters, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "RandomSeed" -> i}], {i, imax}]
```

From 10 sets of parameters, one of them is very close to the NSolve answer:

> {1.96697*10^-16, {c2 -> 0.158201, d2 -> 0.615064, e3a -> -1.74843,
>   c4a -> 47.036, alpha1 -> 0.0606073, alpha3 -> 0.0720952,    beta1 ->
>   0.0248421, beta3 -> 0.0208837, A1 -> 0.000665813,    A3 -> 0.0133163}}

and as it is obvious, the sum of squared equations is of the order $10^{-16}$, while for the exact solution it is of the order $10^{-19}$

```
Eqsa[1.2, 20] /. solexact
```

> {1.47872*10^-19}

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I get after increasing precision and using the default NMinimize function:

```
    In[64]:= mins = 
 NMinimize[{Eqsa[12/10, 20], alpha1 >= 0 && c2 \[Element] Reals}, 
  parameters, WorkingPrecision -> 40]

Out[64]= {1.247337986088467518479435174601049848950*10^-7, {c2 -> \
-0.3374784431690519041004266735008459511493, 
  d2 -> 0.6150685584037689231127591408182094568580, 
  e3a -> 3.668159527211596411791957403610172667566, 
  c4a -> 13.32025714981507468024853784490265246855, 
  alpha1 -> 0.06056083312827593567309553866879351793355, 
  alpha3 -> -0.03436463042452369256834942170851884137055, 
  beta1 -> 0.02494798118128266335488007235487492980332, 
  beta3 -> -0.04373713725729122089474826761167329077141, 
  A1 -> 0.0004748966135853819208165612666379296917031, 
  A3 -> 0.009497932264556549103136017315180242566578}}
```

The error is of the order of 10^-8, which I believe can be further reduced by increasing precision further:

```
In[65]:= (eq1[1.2][[1]] - eq1[1.2][[2]]) /. mins[[2]]

Out[65]= 8.98077*10^-8
```

As a side note: After using Rationalize for all the real values, NSolve gave me {}.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the equations to be very close to zero (at least of the order of 10^-16) or to be more precise my wish is to find  parameters very close to what I found from NSolve with minimization.  Just to remind, A1, A3, alpha1, alpha3, beta1 and beta3 are positive.